# How can I tell what software and updates must be checked or unchecked?

Tags: updates, security, settings

Is there a comprehensive list detailing the software and updates somewhere?
I obviously want my pc as secure as possible but also want everything running smoothly.

In Ubuntu software - everything being checked seems ok? Is that right?

In other software there are 2 unchecked boxes for canonical partners, should they be checked?

In updates everything is checked, is this OK?

I use vlc, web browser, etc that I want to keep updated...Is this the right place I should be looking/checking/unchecking?

Does every download I do add to these lists automatically? I'v just noticed a whole lot of unknown new lists on another pc that are not the same as on this pc and many(that were added) are unchecked?

Where is the best place to read up more on this information to make heads or tails from it?